# tensorflow tfjs-node memory leak

Tags: tensorflow.js

I'm doing some simple experiments with tensorflowjs, after doing some basic image loading and getting the tensor from the image i notice that i was having a memory leak in this operation. here is the code of my test:

```
const tf = require("@tensorflow/tfjs-node");

const fs = require("fs");

counter = 0;

function doProc() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    
    tf.tidy(() => {
      const imgData = fs.readFileSync("/home/rui/teste.png");
      const tensor = tf.node.decodeImage(imgData);

      tf.dispose(tensor);
      
      console.log(`${++counter} - ${process.memoryUsage().rss / 1024 / 1024} MB`)

      console.log('numTensors (in tidy): ' + tf.memory().numTensors);

      //   imgData=null;
    
      
    });

    console.log('numTensors (outside tidy): ' + tf.memory().numTensors);

    doProc();

  }, 250);
}

doProc()
```

here is my output:

```
1 - 124.55859375 MB
numTensors (in tidy): 0
numTensors (outside tidy): 0
2 - 133.48828125 MB
numTensors (in tidy): 0
numTensors (outside tidy): 0
3 - 135.43359375 MB
numTensors (in tidy): 0
numTensors (outside tidy): 0
4 - 136.8671875 MB
numTensors (in tidy): 0
numTensors (outside tidy): 0
5 - 137.265625 MB
numTensors (in tidy): 0
numTensors (outside tidy): 0
6 - 140.24609375 MB
numTensors (in tidy): 0
numTensors (outside tidy): 0
7 - 140.6484375 MB
numTensors (in tidy): 0
numTensors (outside tidy): 0
8 - 140.79296875 MB
numTensors (in tidy): 0
numTensors (outside tidy): 0
9 - 143.7734375 MB
numTensors (in tidy): 0
numTensors (outside tidy): 0
10 - 144.171875 MB
numTensors (in tidy): 0
numTensors (outside tidy): 0
11 - 145.86328125 MB
numTensors (in tidy): 0
numTensors (outside tidy): 0
12 - 147.296875 MB
numTensors (in tidy): 0
numTensors (outside tidy): 0
13 - 147.69921875 MB
numTensors (in tidy): 0
numTensors (outside tidy): 0
14 - 150.421875 MB
numTensors (in tidy): 0
numTensors (outside tidy): 0
15 - 151.078125 MB
numTensors (in tidy): 0
numTensors (outside tidy): 0
16 - 151.22265625 MB
numTensors (in tidy): 0
numTensors (outside tidy): 0
17 - 154.203125 MB
numTensors (in tidy): 0
numTensors (outside tidy): 0
18 - 154.60546875 MB
numTensors (in tidy): 0
numTensors (outside tidy): 0
19 - 155.0078125 MB
numTensors (in tidy): 0
numTensors (outside tidy): 0
20 - 157.73046875 MB
numTensors (in tidy): 0
numTensors (outside tidy): 0
21 - 158.1328125 MB
numTensors (in tidy): 0
numTensors (outside tidy): 0
22 - 159.5625 MB
numTensors (in tidy): 0
numTensors (outside tidy): 0
23 - 161.25390625 MB
numTensors (in tidy): 0
numTensors (outside tidy): 0
24 - 161.9140625 MB
numTensors (in tidy): 0
numTensors (outside tidy): 0
25 - 163.34765625 MB
numTensors (in tidy): 0
numTensors (outside tidy): 0
26 - 155.33203125 MB
numTensors (in tidy): 0
numTensors (outside tidy): 0
27 - 163.25390625 MB
numTensors (in tidy): 0
numTensors (outside tidy): 0
28 - 171.98046875 MB
numTensors (in tidy): 0
numTensors (outside tidy): 0
29 - 180.70703125 MB
numTensors (in tidy): 0
numTensors (outside tidy): 0
30 - 188.91796875 MB
numTensors (in tidy): 0
numTensors (outside tidy): 0
31 - 189.62109375 MB
numTensors (in tidy): 0
numTensors (outside tidy): 0
32 - 198.08984375 MB
numTensors (in tidy): 0
numTensors (outside tidy): 0
33 - 206.5546875 MB
numTensors (in tidy): 0
numTensors (outside tidy): 0
34 - 216.0546875 MB
numTensors (in tidy): 0
numTensors (outside tidy): 0
35 - 224.26171875 MB
numTensors (in tidy): 0
numTensors (outside tidy): 0
36 - 233.24609375 MB
numTensors (in tidy): 0
numTensors (outside tidy): 0
37 - 242.484375 MB
numTensors (in tidy): 0
numTensors (outside tidy): 0
38 - 250.4375 MB
numTensors (in tidy): 0
numTensors (outside tidy): 0
39 - 260.1875 MB
numTensors (in tidy): 0
numTensors (outside tidy): 0
40 - 268.65625 MB
numTensors (in tidy): 0
numTensors (outside tidy): 0
41 - 277.12109375 MB
numTensors (in tidy): 0
numTensors (outside tidy): 0
42 - 277.57421875 MB
numTensors (in tidy): 0
numTensors (outside tidy): 0
43 - 286.296875 MB
numTensors (in tidy): 0
numTensors (outside tidy): 0
44 - 294.765625 MB
numTensors (in tidy): 0
numTensors (outside tidy): 0
45 - 295.46875 MB
numTensors (in tidy): 0
numTensors (outside tidy): 0
46 - 303.6796875 MB
numTensors (in tidy): 0
numTensors (outside tidy): 0
47 - 313.17578125 MB
numTensors (in tidy): 0
numTensors (outside tidy): 0
48 - 321.90625 MB
numTensors (in tidy): 0
numTensors (outside tidy): 0
49 - 329.85546875 MB
numTensors (in tidy): 0
numTensors (outside tidy): 0
```

I don't know what i'm doing wrong and what can i do to avoid this memory leak.

i'm using "@tensorflow/tfjs-node": "^3.2.0"

EDIT:

It seems that the leak happens in node versions 14.x and 15.x, i tested in verison 12.x and there is no leak.